# Matthew 26:29: Why is Jesus talking about the wine here?

Tags: matthew

Matthew 26:29:

> But I say unto you, I will not drink henceforth of this fruit of the
>   vine, until that day when I drink it new with you in my Father's
>   kingdom

Is Jesus speaking about physical wine or some other kind of wine? Why was it necessary for Jesus at this moment to say anything about the wine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At that Passover celebration, several cups of wine would have been drunk at various stages of the ceremony, prior to the cup of wine that Jesus said was “…my blood of the new testament, which is shed for many for the remission of sins” (vs. 28) Having got their attention Big Time with such a startling declaration and invitation to partake of that particular cup of wine, Jesus then said what you quoted in your question.

You ask if the wine in his Father’s kingdom is physical wine or some other type, and why Jesus thought it necessary to speak about wine at that point.

Some people have taken the word ‘new’ to be a clue about ‘new wine’ – ‘the wine of the kingdom’. They would say it won’t be literal wine, but a spiritual kind of drink that can be enjoyed by all believers now that Jesus has returned to heaven, to be with his Father there. He returned to heaven ten days before the outpouring of the Holy Spirit upon the believers in that upper room, at Pentecost, the 50th day after Passover. Many would see that glorious outpouring as ‘the new wine of the kingdom’. Heady stuff, spiritually speaking, given the amazing effects on the believers and the resultant conversion of some 3,000 people as the believers then proclaimed the gospel of the risen Christ to those people from many countries, in their own languages.

However, let it be noted that Jesus said “with you” – requiring himself being in God’s kingdom, and the disciples also being with him, in that kingdom. Jesus will be WITH them and they with him, in the Father’s kingdom. This raises the question of WHEN this mutual drinking of wine can take place. After all, the risen Christ is still in heaven with his return to earth being a future event. Jesus, however, did not say their companionable drinking of this wine would be located on earth – the earthly kingdom of God, if you will. He is speaking of heaven because He knew, at the time he spoke verse 29, that he would be returning to his Father in heaven on the 40th day. That is why he said to Mary Magdalene on the 3rd day that he had not yet returned to the Father (John 20:17). Jesus had previously said to the disciples that he was going to the Father in heaven to prepare a place for them, “so that where I am, you also may be” (John 14:2-3) – in the kingdom of heaven, in heaven.

This is where 1 Corinthians 15:20-28 provides light for we learn that after the Day of Resurrection and Judgement,

> “Then the end, when he shall have delivered up the kingdom to God,
>   even the Father, when he shall have put down all rule and all
>   authority and power. For he must reign till he hath put all his
>   enemies under his feet. The last enemy that shall be destroyed is
>   death.”

That is the point at which all things are restored to how they originally were and the fullness of the glorious kingdom of God is realised, after the Son of God delivers the restored kingdom back to the Father. Then, Revelation tells us, comes the wedding of the Lamb to his spotless bride, “And he that sat upon the throne said, ‘Behold, I make all things new.’ (21:5) That will include new wine – the wine of the kingdom – which surely shall be drunk with joy at the marriage supper of the Lamb, in heaven.

This is not to say that there is also a sense in which the receiving of the Holy Spirit by humans here on earth can be likened to new wine – the wine of the kingdom. There may, indeed, be a foretaste of the wine in heaven by those given to partake of the Holy Spirit before they get to heaven. It’s just that Jesus, on that night, knew all that lay ahead and of the glorious outcome of his death as the Lamb of God, and his resurrection, which would achieve the restoration of the kingdom of God on a cosmic scale, beyond anything his disciples could imagine, that Passover night. The wine of the kingdom, at the marriage of the Lamb, will be wine, but not as we know it! Nothing on earth can fully prepare Christ’s followers for the astounding glory of heaven, including its new wine.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it would appear that Jesus is making reference to literal wine.  This verse is cross-referenced to Acts 10:41 when Peter testified to the bodily resurrection of Jesus:

> "He was not seen by all the people, but by witnesses whom God had already chosen - by us who ate and drank with him after he rose from the dead."

Jesus' words were to assure his followers that he would be physically resurrected.

Comment: But He didn't say "until I raise", but rather "until I drink it new with you in my Father's kingdom".

Comment: @brilliant Jesus did not ascend into heaven until after his resurrection and so he would not drink again with his disciples till they joined him in his Father's heavenly kingdom, is how I understand it.

Comment: If it were all just about resurrection, then He would have drunk the wine with them during the 40 days preceding His ascension; however, He said explicitly, "until that day when I drink it new with you in my Father's kingdom". He didn't say, "until that day when I drink it new with you after my resurrection." One may argue that the moment He resurrected was already the moment He entered His Father's kingdom, but then one would still need to prove that all His disciples also entered the Father's kingdom at that very moment.

Comment: @ brilliant - Consider: **The Father hath delivered us from the power of darkness, and hath translated us us into the Kingdom of His dear Son.** (Col. 1:13) That Jesus had been coronated by this time is evident from His statement to the thief that He would be in Paradise that very day...and His declaration in Matthew 28 that all power in heaven and in earth HAD BEEN GIVEN to Him! (Not "going to be given"...) What do you think?

Comment: @raygrant _ How do we know that Paradise and the Kingdom are one and the same thing?

Comment: @ brilliant - They aren't the same. Paradise is the throne room of God in heaven, as is evident from the usage of this word in the rest of the N.T. (a location).  The Kingdom is the the ruling domain of Jesus which He shares with His disciples. It is spiritual.  'Kingdom' not only refers to Jesus ruling over all powers and spiritual dominions, but to the indwelling of Christ in the hearts of disciples! (Colossians 1:12-20)  What an honor!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to me to be intended as the fulfillment of this prophecy of the post-harvest celebration that was to occur for the laborers:

> [Isaiah 62:8-9 NASB20] (8) The LORD has sworn by His right hand and by His mighty arm: "I will never again give your grain [as] food for your enemies, **Nor will foreigners drink your new wine for which you have labored." (9) But those who harvest it will eat it and praise the LORD; And those who gather it will drink it in the courtyards of My sanctuary.**

And all of these:

> [Genesis 27:28 NLT] (28) "From the dew of heaven and the richness of the earth, may God always give you abundant harvests of grain and bountiful new wine.

> [Numbers 18:12 NLT] (12) "I also give you the harvest gifts brought by the people as offerings to the LORD--the best of the olive oil, new wine, and grain.

> [Deuteronomy 7:13 NLT] (13) He will love you and bless you, and he will give you many children. He will give fertility to your land and your animals. When you arrive in the land he swore to give your ancestors, you will have large harvests of grain, new wine, and olive oil, and great herds of cattle, sheep, and goats.

> [Deuteronomy 11:14 NLT] (14) then he will send the rains in their proper seasons--the early and late rains--so you can bring in your harvests of grain, new wine, and olive oil.

> [Deuteronomy 14:23 NLT] (23) Bring this tithe to the designated place of worship--the place the LORD your God chooses for his name to be honored--and eat it there in his presence. This applies to your tithes of grain, new wine, olive oil, and the firstborn males of your flocks and herds. Doing this will teach you always to fear the LORD your God.

> [Deuteronomy 33:28 NLT] (28) So Israel will live in safety, prosperous Jacob in security, in a land of grain and new wine, while the heavens drop down dew.

Comment: Related:  https://www.quora.com/What-kind-of-wine-did-Jesus-turn-water-into/answer/Bill-Ross-22

Comment: Never heard this before, but it makes a lot of sense. Great insight!

Answer (score 1):

**In the Kingdom!** The emphasis of Jesus's teaching from the beginning of His earthly ministry, throughout until the end, was **the Kingdom of God (Heaven)**. Jesus was to establish His reign on earth to fulfil the Old Testament prophecies to the max!

- Repent for the Kingdom is at hand! (Matthew 4:17,23; 9:35)
- The Kingdom of Heaven is like unto... (Matthew 13:1-52)
- Jesus spoke of the Kingdom of God for 40 days. (Acts 1:3)

And so here it was appropriate for Jesus to announce to His disciples during the important Last Supper ceremony, the imminence of the Kingdom:  *I will not drink...until in My Father's Kingdom.*

So the great glaring question flashes in our minds like a Broadway sign: Has this occurred, and if so, when? The answer is not left to our own devices. The answer is found in the Acts of the Apostles.

> He (Jesus) ate and drank with us. (Acts 10:41)

This statement was forthcoming when Peter explained to the household of Cornelius that Jesus was indeed God resurrected from the dead, and was manifested to eye-witnesses in an empirical way.

Jesus spent 40 days after the resurrection speaking about the "Kingdom of God" because He was the most immanent expert on the subject:  He was its **King**! He was quite proficient on the topic. Which is contrasted to the ignorance of the disciples, as was evident by their questioning in Acts 1:6.

After Jesus's teaching--and after the Holy Spirit out-pouring--the disciples never spoke of a physical kingdom in a physical Israel! In fact, it was just a few decades later that the whole of Judea with its Temple would be razed to the ground!!! Totally wiped out by the Romans. So if the anticipation of the disciples had been carried out, that physical kingdom would have been quickly destroyed! But no; Jesus wasn't interest in real estate, but in real people of character. **The Kingdom of God is not (physical) meat or drink, but righteousness, peace, and joy in the Holy Ghost.**

The statement of Jesus at the Last Supper was not dealing with wine or grape juice per se, but the main topic was the symbolism pointing to the great manifestation of the Kingdom on earth which was to be established by the work of the Church.

> **I appoint unto you a Kingdom, as my Father hath appointed unto Me...** (Luke 22:29; Compare Daniel 7, "It came time for the saints to obtain the Kingdom.")

Comment: WOW! This is something! Thanks a lot! However, I still can't hide away from the question: How do we know that Acts 10:41 implies wine for sure? I understand that the main point in Matthew 26:29 is kingdom; however, unlike in Acts 10:41, Jesus doesn't just say "eat and drink", but speaks specifically of the fruit of the vine, that is, wine. Another thing that is kind of bugging me is the disciples' question right before His ascension: "Are you at this time going to restore the kingdom?" and His His immediate answer in Acts 1 - both implying that the kingdom was not come yet.

Comment: @ brilliant - Good questions. First: after the resurrection Jesus was with the disciples  for 40 days. It is highly probable that when eating with them they used wine to drink since there were no other drinks available in the first century. It was safer than just water since there was no refrigeration, etc.  When Jesus  invited the fishermen to "come and dine" the bread and fish would have been hard to swallow without drink as well (John 21:121). Secondly, it is true the disciples "asked" but this wasn't the first time they asked inappropriate questions (questions based on false understand)...

Comment: @ brilliant - ...When Jesus put off His answer in Acts, He directed them to the Holy Spirit anointing soon to come to pass.  And after that infilling, the Apostles never spoke of a physical Kingdom again. Their eyes were enlightened to the establishment of a spiritual Kingdom, with Jesus as coronated King. It was on the basis of this fact that Jesus gave the Great Commission (Mtt 28:18-19).  **We have been translated into the Kingdom of His dear Son.** (Col. 1:13, 1 Thess 2:12, 2 Thess 1:5) **Wherefore we receiving a kingdom which cannot be moved, let us...** (Hebrews 12:28)   Peace!

Comment: John 2:7 and John 4:7 show that they DID drink water in those times.

Comment: @  Thanks for the input. John 2:7 underscores the need for "water to be purified" (vs. 6), and wine to be preferred.  And "well water" would seem to be most safe to drink. (4:7). Still, it is hard to expect that for 40 days Jesus never touched some wine. (Acts 10:41). And we know from other scriptures, the Kingdom DID come (according to the Apostles' writings.) so Jesus had to have drank some wine!  I wish the Bible authors would have been more specific and direct, eh?

Answer (score 0):

### Does Matthew 26:29 Really Mean "Wine"?

It seems to me that Jesus **is saying nothing about wine**. Rather, He is referring merely to "fruit of the vine" as in *grape juice*. This appears to be a common misconception, that the Lord would expect us (including alcoholics) to imbibe in wine as a crucial part of worship: **communion**, a "common union" with Him. How would this not represent a significant stumbling block to *those who cannot drink at all*?

Some may point to the Book of Proverbs where it states,

> **Proverbs 31:6-7**: Give strong drink to one who is perishing, and wine to the bitter in soul. Let him drink and forget his poverty, and remember his misery no more.

However, is this the correct way to view alcohol consumption? Or should we not understand this verse in the context intended? First, the letter states that it is:

> **Proverbs 31:1**: "The words of King Lemuel. An oracle that his mother taught him."

What is important is to reflect on verses 4-5:

> **Proverbs 31:4-5**: "It is not for kings, O Lemuel, it is not for kings to drink wine, or for rulers to crave strong drink, lest they drink and forget what is decreed, depriving all the oppressed of justice."

This is a warning from the queen-mother saying: "Stay away from alcohol! It impairs one's judgment and leads to poor decisions over the people. Allow the subjects to drink as they may, but as for you, it is improper."

I would suggest that, in most cases, the phrase "fruit of the vine" is being terribly misinterpreted as "wine," where there are no such statements. It seems presumptuous to immediately label "fruit of the vine" as such when neither the text nor the context calls for it.

The first reference to someone drinking wine in the O/T was Noah. It clearly states in Genesis 9:

> **Genesis 9:21**: "He drank some of the wine and became drunk, and uncovered himself inside his tent."

This led to, at the very least, great embarrassment for Noah. (When does alcohol **not** do so?) While we may not know the precise details of the account, Noah was deeply affected. This was probably meant as a warning to everyone that alcohol consumption often has adverse effects.

The reality is that drinking alcohol by most people is a bad idea. It almost immediately leads to poor judgment. In the context above, the king must remain diligent and alert (*as must the faithful*) to rule the kingdom even though some of the suffering poor will resort to drunkenness to ease their heartache and misery. There is no recommendation here for anyone to drink alcohol other than to ease **severe**, physical suffering, and mental anguish for those who are probably about to die (vss. 6-7).

The lesson for the faithful is this: It is imprudent to consume alcohol. We must remain sober-minded as role models, lights to the world, to serve the interests of others (Matt. 5:14, **Eph. 5:18**).

Comment: Thank you for this input, but I would want to know why Jesus mentioned the fruit of the vine (whatever is implied by it) in that last supper in the first place? Why was it so important to talk about that on the night when He was about to be taken?

Comment: @brilliant - The fruit of the vine (grape fruit juice) is representative of Christ's blood. When you partake of the bread (Jesus' broken body) then the fruit of the vine (**life** through His blood), you are continually cleansed of all sin and all unrighteousness. Of course, a life of faithful obedience does this for us, but it is *disobedient* to Christ's commandment in Luke 22:19-20 to ignore this biblical imperative.

Comment: I understand all of that, but I still don't understand why He said that He wouldn't drink of the fruit of the wine until the kingdom of God shall come, in Luke 22:18.

Comment: @brilliant - Oh, sorry. Well, Christ was about to allow Himself to be murdered by torture as The Sacrifice for all humanity. In other words, He hadn't yet died and communion is a memorial of the Lord's Sacrifice: His death. Naturally, that had not yet occurred, but He had instituted the Lord's Supper for us all in that moment. Christ's Kingdom was inaugurated on Pentecost in the first century. In Luke, He states: "But I say to you truthfully, there are some of those standing here who will not taste death until they see the kingdom of God" (Lk. 9:27). He is **now** the King of all the earth.

Comment: If you are going to argue that this is grape juice, you need to illustrate the semantic range of wine in the Greek is sometimes used that way. Also, how would freely drinking grape juice lead to the inability to discern inferior juice from good juice?